# Merit Gem: how to grab a User's points for a single day?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, points, merit-gem

How can I grab a User's points for a single day (i.e. 'Today' or 'Yesterday') using the Merit gem?

I tried:

```
current_user.points.where("created_at >= ?", Time.zone.now.beginning_of_day)
```

but that doesn't work.

Comment: I think you should look at the source of the gem. For example [this is method `points`](https://github.com/tute/merit/blob/master/lib/merit/models/active_record/merit/score.rb#L47) and it returns number! But you can see that number is a result of query to `score_points`. I think you have a chance to fetch points for a day if you manage to add a scope to the table `score_points`. Maybe you can override the whole method `points`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a models diagram for merit in https://github.com/tute/merit/wiki/General-merit-workflow. With that in mind, lines like this makes it work:

```
user = User.first
points = user.sash.scores.first.score_points
points.where("created_at > '#{Time.zone.now.beginning_of_day}'")
```

Comment: I got it working with the full line as follows: u.sash.scores.first.score_points.where("created_at > ?", Time.zone.now.beginning_of_day).sum(:num_points)

Answer (score 0):

This is the final answer:

```
u.sash.scores.first.score_points.where("created_at > ?", Time.zone.now.beginning_of_day).sum(:num_points)
```

Thanks TuteC.